# Central administration is displayed wrong

Tags: central-administration, installation, 403

Just after installation of sharepoint 2010 I opened central administration it looked weird, like no styles and js had been loaded. A screenshot of CA and js-errors in console is presented here: 
https://rapidshare.com/files/2648149066/Sharepoint-CA-403.png

Small description in console: 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
    http://pc4:2430/_layouts/1049/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=NUH7%2FvckrAqUWYMSpN1KsQ%3D%3D

I've checked permissions and found out that NETWORK SERVICE has a proper access-rights (full access) to a virtual directory of the application and to folder 'web extensions/14' of sharepoint. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in SharePoint 2007 a couple of times. What helped me was to go to the template folder in the 14 Hive and replace the permissions on all child elements in the file system. It never happens in any productive environment but on development Servers and only for development environments i would recommend this procedure.

After that everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan! Right now I can't use your advice in pratice. By the way, by 'replace the permissions on all child elements in the file system' what do you mean exactly? To add needed permissions (i.e. for NETWORK SERVICE) for folder 14/HIVE?

Comment: On Template Folder -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Change Permission -> Replace all child object permissions with inheratable permission from this object.